# How to Determine Windows Phone OS Version

Tags: windows-phone-8

I need to determine whether the user has 8 or 8.1 on their device. What is the best way to accomplish this? The exact version number is of no concern, I just need to know if they've upgraded their OS so I can know whether to include some new 8.1 features or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Environment.OSVersion.Version`. It returns the version of the OS. Note that for WP 8.1 the version is  actually 8.10.

You can check if the phone is updated to WP 8.1 like this:

```
if (Environment.OSVersion.Version >= new Version(8, 10)) {
    // The user is using WP 8.1 or later
}
```

Comment: In Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows (Universal or WP8.1 app), System.Environment does not contain a definition for OSVersion

Comment: @bdimag Sure, but you know, if the app is Universal/WP8.1 app... it is known that the user has updated to version 8.1! Those do not run on WP8.0, if you didn't know. So I assumed that he would need to know that from a WP8.0 or earlier app in which case - that's the way to do it.

Comment: Can you "include some new 8.1 features" in a WP8 app?

Comment: @bdimag Sure, using reflection. That's quite common. Well, not all features can be included like that, but for a lot of them it works, and this way you don't have to support two versions of the app.